# How to use slash commands in Discum

Tags: discord.py, slash, discum

I want to use it to trigger slash commands from other bots. As an example, I want to let the self bot write /ping and the Dankmemer should recognize that and respond. I have already tried to do this.

My first problem is the script runs error free, but nothing happens (the selfbot doesn't write the message or command to the channel).

The second problem is when I try to do the same with the disboard bot or other bots, the reading of the commands from the bot no longer works. In other words if I let the script read all commands from the Dankmemer bot, I get the whole list of slash commands.

But when I read the disboard bot I get

> {'message': 'You are not authorized to perform this action on this application', 'code': 20012}

as an output. When I try the whole thing on the Mee6 bot I only get [ ] this empty bracket out.

How can I do this?

https://gist.github.com/BinBeiNetto/63806b1a516507f01fc551f8b6e65945

Answer (score 0):

Bots cannot interact with bots. If you used a normal user as a bot that’s against the [TOS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TOS#Noun).